# EWS API usage service ResolveName

Tags: ews-managed-api

I am trying to resolve name using ExchangeService::ResolveName API

But problem is the Contact ItemId is always null, though there is a match

```
NameResolutionCollection matchingnames = service.ResolveName("X@X.com",     ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true);
        foreach (NameResolution item in matchingnames)
        {
            Contact contact = item.Contact;
            contact.ItemId // This is always NULL irrespective 

        }
```

Am I doing something wrong
How can I dig-down the contact details..like profile picture I can't do it as ItemId for contact is NULL always

Answer (score 0):

I also observed on my environment that "contact" is always set to "`null`" for each `NameResolutionCollection` item, but the Mailbox property is filled.

So you can try this:

```
EmailAddress address = item.Mailbox;
String Name = address.Name.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to include the PropertySet argument to include first-class properties, 
[outlined here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.resolvename?view=exchange-ews-api#Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_ExchangeService_ResolveName_System_String_Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_ResolveNameSearchLocation_System_Boolean_Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_PropertySet_)... [More information about PropertySet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/email-properties-and-elements-in-ews-in-exchange#first-class-properties-and-elements-for-email-messages).

```
NameResolutionCollection matchingnames = service.ResolveName("X@X.com", ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
```